# Сортировка результатов поиска MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица из 3 полей (`id, author, title`). В таблице порядка 10 тысяч записей.

Нужно сделать поиск по 2 полям `author, title`.

Например ищем "Иванов":

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE author = "Иванов" OR title = "Иванов".
```

Но результат нужно вывести таким образом, чтобы сначала шли все совпадения по `author` и только затем по `title`.

Каким способом это можно сделать в `mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE author = 'Иванов' OR title = 'Иванов'
order by case when author = 'Иванов' then 0 else 1 end
```

[CASE в ORDER BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html)

Answer (score 2):

Еще так можно:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE author = "Иванов" OR title = "Иванов"
ORDER by FIELD("Иванов",author,title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE author = "Иванов"
union all
SELECT * FROM table WHERE author != "Иванов" and title = "Иванов"
```

Union объединяет.

П.с. можно и одним запросом:

```
SELECT *, if(author="Иванов";1;0) as `author_match` FROM table WHERE author = "Иванов" or title = "Иванов" order by `author_match` desc
```

Но кто из них быстрее, нагляднее и удобнее - оцените сами.